# Laravel migrate command

Tags: database, laravel, migration, migrate

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I have problem with migrations . ( I am a beginner )

when I create a table, there is no problem, but when I run **`php artisan migrate`** this error show up :

> [PDOException]
>       SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'homestead'

**my env file data :**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**my config/database.php file :**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'engine'    => null,
],
```

my app env use 'local' , but I can't run this command .

I'm just running **`php -S localhost:8888 -t public`** to access localhost and I don't run anything else . should I run anything else ?

pre thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

yes. you should setup a database for the application. The configurations you posted assumes that there is a local mysql database server running and there is a database called  'homestead'. so   `Unknown database 'homestead'` is just means what is says.

if you dont have a local mysql server, you can use sqlite which laravel supports as well.

Edit: 
if you have a mysql server then just create a database called 'homestead' or whatever you like then change the configurations accordingly.

Alternatively, use the full stack that Laravel offers and consider using Homestead with Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Create database in mysql 
and change `DB_DATABASE=homestead` to `DB_DATABASE=your_database name`